# How to combine (row 1 column 1), (row 2 column1), (row 3 column 1), and (row 4 column1)

Tags: kotlin, android-cardview, android-tablelayout

Good evening sir/ma'am. Sorry for disturb your time. I am a student from Indonesia . I have a problem in make table with kotlin using card view. My lecturer gave me a design which i should make. This table design like this [image which my lecture gave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZqxR.jpg). So, I tried make this
[My Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Xt2.png). So, my question is how to combine (row 1, col 1),(row 2, col 1), (row 3, col 1), (row 4, col 1) ([my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWRxy.png)) in my table layout? So that, the image will look center in the table. It is possible or not sir? That's all my question. Thank you verymuch.
This is my cardView code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardBarang"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray">

            <TableLayout
                android:centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/tbl2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                >

                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:text="Nama Barang"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_span="1"
                        android:id="@+id/gambar"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/laptop2"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_span="1"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:text="Keterangan"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:text="Harga"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_width="50px"
                        android:layout_height="50px"
                        android:src="@drawable/love"
                        android:paddingLeft="70dp"

                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:id="@+id/promo"
                        android:text="Promo"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/red"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```